# When to use ''[verb] that''

Tags: grammar

I would like to know when to say *think(s) that*, *say(s) that* and *mean(s) that* and when to omit *that*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most cases, if any of these verbs is followed by an embedded clause, *that* is completely optional.

> He said he was coming.
>
> He said that he was coming.

are both completely grammatical, and normal in speech. The form with *that* is probably slightly more formal, so you're more likely to encounter it in writing than in speech; but both occur in both speech and writing.

There is a lot of scholarly literature on the subject of "that-deletion", for example [this paper](http://www.thefreelibrary.com/Toward+a+semantic+account+of+that-deletion+in+English+*.-a0132963932), which says "It has implicitly been assumed in the literature that the language arbitrarily allows sentence-embedding predicates, such as the ones in (1), to embed their sentential complements with or without the complementizer that".

But the paper does give some cases where *that* may not be deleted, such as

> Mary said in a very loud voice that she would not eat the cookies.

where, apparently because of the intervening prepositional phrase, *that* is required (at least for most speakers).

So, in short, with these particular verbs, you are never wrong to include *that*, but in ordinary speech or informal writing, as long as the clause comes straight after the verb you may omit it.

Comment: Likewise, _that_-clauses at the beginning of the sentence require _that_: _That she left early is a shame_ vs **She left early is a shame*. The basic principle is that if the matrix verb governing the complement is not immediately before the clause, the need for a clause marker increases greatly, since the verb no longer provides a parse guide. Similar remarks apply to *for-to* deletion with infinitives, and many other marker words, like determiners, prepositions, and auxiliaries. If you don't get the usual cues, you rely on the redundant ones, just like normal.